# UIActivityIndicatorView/detachNewThreadSelector

Tags: uiactivityindicatorview

I am using UIActivityIndicatorView for the first time in an iPhone app, in order to let the user know that some process is on the way.
To do that I use the detachNewThreadSelector method (also for the first time).

I end up with code like this:

```
[myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(theWorkToBeDone:) toTarget:self withObject:myObject];
```

The problem is that when I time the application. It takes about 5 times longer to perform the task when I use the code above than when I do not use UIActivityIndicatorView and detachNewThreadSelector. (In which case the user still waits, but a shorter time).

Is this difference in timing what I should expect when using UIActivityIndicatorView ?

Or am I making some beginner mistake due to my inexperience with both UIActivityIndicatorView and detachNewThreadSelector?

Thanks for any bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that adding this line a the beginning of the theWorkToBeDone method:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

and this one at the end:

```
[pool release];
```

solves my problem.